# Is the Spark Java framework compatible with Java 17?

Tags: java-17, spark-java

Spark - a tiny web framework for Java 8

https://sparkjava.com/

It's always mentioned that this framework is for Java 8. Can anyone confirm that this framework is forward compatible? Can we use the older versions of this framework for Java 17? Or do we need use the latest version of the framework for Java 17? Is there any Java compatibility matrix for this framework versions? Please help me with the link if we have such thing.

I read the documentation, but I didn't find whether this is forward compatible or not. I also did not find any Java compatibility matrix.

Comment: You're asking too many questions, and we can't vouch for the compatibility of or give recommendations for third-party libraries. You need to ask that third-party. Judging by some of the issues (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/1266)) the current version might not be Java 17 compatible. But bar explicit mentions in the documentation, or communication from the author of this library, the only option you have is to test and verify yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I have used SparkJava in production with Java 17 since 2022-12-09 and have not had any Java 17 related issues.

Before that, we used Java 11 from 2020-04-06.

The only difference I have seen in our production environment is that we are using less memory with Java 17 than with Java 11.

Try it yourself and see if you have any issues. It works great for us.

Comment: What was Spark version?

Comment: We are on 2.9.4

Answer (score 1):

Let's see and not try to guess.

The dependency, that `sparkjava.com` [demonstrates](https://sparkjava.com/download) to be used is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

If we'll open its [`pom.xml`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sparkjava/spark-core/2.9.4/spark-core-2.9.4.pom), we'll see this:

```xml
<properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <jetty.version>9.4.48.v20220622</jetty.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <powermock.version>1.7.4</powermock.version>
  <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
</properties>
```

This means, that there is no *explicit* support for Java 17 and features that pertain to Java 17 specifically, **may** not work.